# Using JSON Path to update value in json with a json object

Tags: java, scala, jsonpath

I have two json files. One is the file i wish to update and the other is the file i read the value from. My issue is that the value to be overridden needs to be overridden by another object. When i use JSON path library, i get a null map in the value space.

Example:

```
val sourceConfigStr =
  """
    |{
    |   "path": {
    |                    "dummyKey1" : "nothing",
    |                    "dummyKey2" : "data.csv"
    |                 },
    |   "format": "RANDOM",
    |   "schema": "schema.json"
    |}
  """.stripMargin;

val modifiedString = JsonPath.parse(sourceConfigStr).set("$.path.dummyKey1", Map("dummyKey13" ->  "Hello")).jsonString()
val modifiedSource = JsonUtil.fromJson[Map[String,Any]](modifiedString);
println(modifiedSource)

Output : Map(path -> Map(dummyKey1 -> Map(), dummyKey2 -> data.csv), format -> RANDOM, schema -> schema.json)
```

As you can see, the dummyKey1 got replaced by a null Map(). How do i fix this?

Update: This issue exists because the .set() function requires a String value. So, i created a json string and tried passing that. However, now my output has backslash and " ". How do i make it a uniform JSON?

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can use [Dijon](https://github.com/pathikrit/dijon) to safely and handy read, update, and serialize schema-less JSON values:

```
val sourceConfigStr =
  """
    |{
    |   "path": {
    |                    "dummyKey1" : "nothing",
    |                    "dummyKey2" : "data.csv"
    |                 },
    |   "format": "RANDOM",
    |   "schema": "schema.json"
    |}
  """.stripMargin

val json = parse(sourceConfigStr)
json.path.dummyKey1 = json"""{"dummyKey13":"Hello"}"""
println(json)
```

Expected output:

```
{"path":{"dummyKey1":{"dummyKey13":"Hello"},"dummyKey2":"data.csv"},"format":"RANDOM","schema":"schema.json"}
```

Comment: I was looking for a generic way to do it. I dont know to what depth i would need to go.

Comment: You could try [JSLT](https://github.com/schibsted/jslt), which is a transform language for JSON that can be easily invoked from Java/Scala code.